# Extraneous positional argument error (Yarn) when using JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-lab, yarnpkg-v2, yarn-v2

When I run

```
jupyter lab
```

I get

```
Fail to get yarn configuration. Unknown Syntax Error: Extraneous positional argument ("list").

$ yarn config [-v,--verbose] [--why] [--json]
```

This is new to me (I've been using `jupyter` for years without issues) and seems to have started after I switched to Yarn Modern with

```
yarn set version berry
```

I thought perhaps that the issue might be the presence of

```
nodeLinker: pnp
```

in my `.yarnrc.yml` but replacing that with

```
nodeLinker: node-modules
```

doesn't fix anything.

FWIW, `.yarnrc.yml` also has

```
yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.2.3.cjs
```

How do I fix this fatal error?

Comment: This should not happen. JupyterLab uses `jlpm` which is version locked yarn alias [defined here](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/6df5e0b6e8ec740ffa2f84f198820d1968e4d74d/jupyterlab/jlpmapp.py). If your configuration influences which yarn version gets used by `jlpm`, it seems strange. One potential solution would be to attempt running `jlpm set version self` (and if it works adding it to `jlpmapp.py` for robustness).

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/12848. It is really strange that yarn switches to different version since all [commands](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/blob/3.4.x/jupyterlab/commands.py) use the version-locked `YARN_PATH` (also known as jlpm).